# Type for all Omits of class/interface/type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

If I have a type:

```
type MyType = {
    ...
    propertyA: string;
    propertyB: number;
    ...
}
```

how can I type this in another type but allow all versions of it with properties omitted? Such as:

```
type MyOtherType = {
    propertyC: MyType | Omit<MyType, ANYTHING>;
}
```

I have tried `Omit<MyType, any>` but that removes the types of other properties on the object.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you means make all of them optional (`Partial`), you can try to use [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) instead:

```
type MyType = {
    ...
    propertyA: string;
    propertyB: number;
    ...
}

type MyOtherType = {
    propertyC: MyType | Partial<MyType>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using a library that uses a builder pattern. Depending on what methods are called on it, it will return either the full class or an omit of it. So would I have to make all options optional or is there a way to just accept all omits?

Comment: Hi @SirGolem, I am not quite sure about what you mean by all omits, omitting everything means an empty object `{}`?

Comment: The builder can sometimes return MyClass but sometimes Omit<MyClass, "addField" | "addTitle">, where the omitted fields are from a long list and vary a lot based on usage. Some fields are never omitted though and so making them optional means more checks. I was just wondering if I can have a type that accepts all combinations of omits of a class.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve? If you want it to generate different combination such as: `{} | { a: number } | { b: string } | { a: number; b: string }`, isn't this ultimately the same as `Partial<T>`?

Comment: The class has some properties that are always required, and some methods that are omitted by some method calls. I was just wondering if I could keep properties required while accepting omits but it seems that this probably isn't something I can do.

Comment: "The class has some properties that are always required, and some methods that are omitted by some method calls." If this matters enough to accept/reject an answer, you should put a [mre] of it in your question.  Right now the only thing anyone can suggest is `Partial` because there's not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly. You might use the `Partial` utility type to make all props of MyType optional and then use Omit to remove any property you want from it.

```
type MyOtherType = {
    propertyC: MyType | Omit<Partial<MyType>, 'propertyA'>;
}
```

It is an example. So I removed `propertyA` from MyType. You can remove other property with replacing 'propertyA' with the name of that property.